# PHPMailer custom different subject line for CC, From and To

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to implement a custom or different subject line for CC, From and To.

```
$to = "To";
$from = "From";
$CC = "CC";

$mail->Subject  = 'Dynamic Subject Line';
```

Thanks and Much Appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do that in a regular email, so I assume it cannot be done with PHPMailer (assuming you want to only send a single email).

Comment: Add your research / code in the question.

Comment: You would have to split it up in to one group of recipients per subject line. There's no way to do it with a single email.

Comment: Indeed, this isn't possible - if you want different subjects, send separate messages.